# How can I find the name of an image in an array in p5.js?

Tags: arrays, p5.js

I have an array of images in p5.js. I want to get the *name* of one image in the array (br), but I do not want the information about it. How can I do this?

So far I have tried using `console.log`, but that gives me information about the image, such as

```
{width: 90, height: 90, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, drawingContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D, _pixelsState: Object…}
```

but not the actual name of it.
Here is my code:

```
function preload() {
  br = loadImage("br.png");
  board = [br]
}

function draw() {
  console.log(board[0])
  background(220);
}
```

Comment: Could you keep an array of objects? One key for the name, one key for the image.

Comment: Not sure if the image name is stored using the load image method. It seems more like it stores just the image data, and treats the image name purely as a path to the image it has to load in. Why not load them into a dictionary with key:value being name:image_data ?

Comment: I have tried using an array of objects instead now. It gives me the desired effect.